# I want to bulkify my trigger! Could somebody help me with this

Tags: trigger

```
trigger NewTrigger on Candidate__c (after insert, after delete, after update) {
    Log_Object__c log=new Log_Object__c();
    boolean check=false;
    if (Trigger.isInsert)
    {
        log.Candidate_Name__c=Trigger.new[0].First_Name__c;
        log.Status__c='Insert';
        log.Modified__c=Trigger.new[0].ownerId;
        check=true;
    }
    if(Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        log.Candidate_Name__c=Trigger.new[0].First_Name__c;
        log.Status__c='Updated';
        log.Modified__c=Trigger.new[0].ownerId;
        check=true;
    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete)
    {
        log.Candidate_Name__c=Trigger.new[0].First_Name__c;
        log.Status__c='Deleted';
        log.Modified__c=Trigger.new[0].ownerId;
        check=true;
    }
    if(check){
        insert log;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an SObject constructor and some ternary operators, and you have some simple code.

```
trigger NewTrigger on Candidate__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    Log_Object__c[] logs = new Log_Object__c[0];
    for(Candidate__c record: Trigger.new == null? Trigger.old: Trigger.new) {
        logs.add(new Log_Object__c(Candidate_Name__c=record.First_Name__c, Status__c=Trigger.isinsert?'Insert':(Trigger.isUpdate?'Update':'Delete'), Modified__c=record.OwnerId));
    }
    insert logs;
}
```

Note that we don't need to check if there are log items, because empty lists are no-ops, but even if they were, there will always be a least one log (your trigger wouldn't fire if there were no records to process). Finally, Trigger.new is null during a delete, so use Trigger.old in that case.